# how to pass password in flask route

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am using flask and want to create a url which is a post request and contains "username" and "password" as a string in url

```
@app.route('/login/<username>/<password>')
def login(username,password):
return password
```

My Url should look like this

> http://192.158.42.102:8080/login/iamuser/iamuser##123

But the problem is that password is truncated to "iamuser##123" to "iamuser" , How can I pass the full passowrd as string.

```
@app.route('/login/<username>/<string:password>')
```

But still it is returning "iamuser" . Can anyone resolve this issue so that I could pass any string to the url. I do not want to use the form for posting the request

Comment: If you can change the requirements, passwords should not be passed in the URL, but in an [Authentication header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19514538/2745495) or in a [request form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61966473/2745495). That way, in can still contain special characters and not conflict with URL special characters, such as `#`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send password to REST service securely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514538/how-to-send-password-to-rest-service-securely) (I know this isn't really answering the question, but I don't want to suggest other solutions that will let you pass password in the URL. The answer in that link is a much better way to go.)

Comment: Please note that it is **extremely dangerous** to include password (sensitive information) in request URL (path parameter, or query strings), as web-servers and proxies tend to log request URLs, which could leak sensitive user information.

Comment: Do not put passwords or other secrets into the URL. It will be stored in the browser history and web log and possibly at other places as well.

Comment: I guess he thinks to a hashed_password..